# Convert HTML 5 canvas drawing into format readable by 3D printer?

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, html5-canvas

Is it possible to convert a HTML 5 canvas drawing into a file readable by 3D printers (e.g., .ply, .sty)?

We couldn't find any libraries that exist ... does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 2):

The drawing on a HTML5 canvas is a pixel based images. 3D printers expect vector based formats. So technically you'd have to vectorize the image first.

Since drawing on a HTML5 canvas requires to perform drawing operations, the straightforward way was to log the drawing operations to turn those into a vector based format.

Another method would be *not* using a HTML5 canvas, but creating a SVG DOM. SVG by it's nature is a vector format; also a lot of the tools used to prepare a 3D printing control file either accept SVG directly, or formats for which SVG convertors exist for.

Comment: cool, thanks. have you had any experience doing this yourself? any resources in particular (aside from google) you recommend for learning more?